# Net Core 2.0 pass data from IPageFilter Attribute to Razor Pages PageModel

Tags: c#, attributes, .net-core, razor-pages

How can i pass data(object) from IPageFilter Attribute to Razor Page PageModel. Can i create a **ViewData["example"] = object** in this filter?

I can do it like this;

```
    public void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
         //i want like this
        //ViewData["Member"] = memberUser;

        context.HttpContext.Items.Add("Member", memberUser);
    }
```

But i must get everytime this object from Items.

Any way can i do this work with ViewData or TempData ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  `ViewData` and `TempData` are only relevant to a `PageResult` and the filter pipeline doesn't even know what the `Result` will be.

The annoying thing is that the `PageContext`, which is used to create the `PageHandlerXXXXContext`, does have a `ViewData` property but you can't access it from the `IPageFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the selected PageModel through the context's `HandlerInstance` property, like this:

```
public void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context) {
    var pageModel = context.HandlerInstance as PageModel ??
        throw new Exception("This page filter must run in a PageModel.");

    pageModel.ViewData["Member"] = memberUser;
    ...
}
```

Considering that a `IPageFilter` is for Razor Pages only, I cannot see how `HandlerInstance` could ever be anything except a PageModel, but if anyone knows otherwise please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

If you not define page model class for page then "HandlerInstance as PageModel" is always be null. In this case need to check as Page:

```
public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
{
    PageContext pageContext = null;

    if (context.HandlerInstance is Page page) { pageContext = page.PageContext; }
    else if(context.HandlerInstance is PageModel pageModel) { pageContext = pageModel.PageContext; }

    if (pageContext != null)
    {
        pageContext.ViewData["UserEmail"] = "email";
    }

    await next.Invoke();
}
```